# How to use \lowertitleback without \maketitle but with titlepage

Tags: titles, koma-script

I am using the KOMA class `scrbook` and I would like to use `\uppertitleback` and `\lowertitleback` even though I do not want to use `\maketitle` but use my own `titlepage`. If I understood the KOMA documentation correctly, `\uppertitleback` is typeset when `\maketitle` is called, therefore, the following example will not contain any titles on the back of the titlepage once typeset, as expected.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
My Title Page
\end{titlepage}
\uppertitleback{Lorem}
\lowertitleback{Ipsum}
\end{document}
```

Is there an elegant solution to this problem or do I have to resort to something like the following?

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
Text at the top of the page
\vfill
Text at the bottom
```

Comment: The thing is, `\maketitle` places the stuff you saved in variables (title, author, lowertitleback etc.). The `titlepage` environment gives you the *freedom* to place *everything* by hand.  You can have more than one titlepage.

Comment: Are there any news here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want the predefined title, you have to do it by hand. Everything. So no, there is no elegant way, you decide where the stuff goes and what it looks like.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \vspace*{.3\textheight}
    \centering
    {\Huge\sffamily Platypus X\par}
    \vspace{.1\textheight}
    {\Large\scshape Papa Patata\par}
\end{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Lorem

\vfill
Ipsum
\clearpage
\end{document}
```