# Use \uppertitleback and \lowertitleback with full-page PDF cover

Tags: koma-script

I have to include a (full-page) PDF as the cover of my thesis, which I'm currently doing via `pdfpages`'s `\includepdf`. Unfortunately, I don't know how to combine this with `\uppertitleback` and `\lowertitleback` from KOMA-Script:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf{cover.pdf}

\uppertitleback{Foo}
\lowertitleback{Bar}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

`\maketitle`, of course, complains that no title was given. But `\title` inserts a new page.

Any ideas? Or do I have to do it by hand as suggested by [Johannes_B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283885/92943)?

Comment: I honestly think that making what you want by hand is the most easiest and fastesy way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Johannes_B you're probably right—will add that as an answer and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Johannes_B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283885/92943), I did it as follows (which yields the same result):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf{resources/cover.pdf}

\thispagestyle{empty}
Foo
\vfill
Bar
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't even need the titlepage emvironment, it is useless here. See integrating the titlepage at https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation